# Tapestry 5.3: Ajax call on page load

Tags: java, ajax, web, tapestry

Using Apache Tapestry 5.3, I am looking for a way to call an ajax action immediately after a page has been loaded. Unfortunately, the [Tapestry Documentation](https://tapestry.apache.org/ajax-and-zones.html) only seems to explain how to invoke an ajax action with an action link. In my situation, I would like to load the page content through ajax when the page is loaded (async content).

I did try something like the following:

```
@PageAttached
void onAjax() {
    ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender("middlezone", block);
}
```

But this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Place the ajax request inside afterRender method, which will get called after the page is loaded.

```
    void afterRender() {
      ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender("middlezone", block);
    }
```